# I think I have come up with the worst way to compare two dates; is it possible to make it better?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

My app accepts a date form the user through a datepicker fragment and stores it in a database with the day, month and year as individual columns of type String.

Now, I'm creating a function which will later check each of these dates with the current date of the system. If the current date is ahead of the date entered by the user (and stored in the database) a flag variable is incremented.

Here is the code:

```
public int checkDate() {                                    //Method to check date and take action
                                                                                //NOT COMPLETE. STILL FIGURING IT OUT.  

        String isstatus = "Ongoing";
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, DAY, MONTH, YEAR ,PROJECT_STATUS}; 
        Cursor c = projectDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, PROJECT_STATUS + "=" + isstatus, null, null, null, null);
        int result = 0;
        int flag = 0;

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iDay = c.getColumnIndex(DAY);
        int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(MONTH);
        int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(YEAR);

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                        //fetch current system date
        int cyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int cmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int cday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

            String id = c.getString(iRow);

            int fday = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iDay));
            int fmonth = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMonth));
            int fyear = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iYear));

            if(cday>fday && cmonth>fmonth && cyear>fyear) {

                flag++;
                updateStatus(id, "Missed");

            }

               else

            if(cday>fday && cmonth==fmonth && cyear==fyear) {

                flag++;
                updateStatus(id, "Missed");

            }

               else

            if(cday==fday && cmonth>fmonth && cyear>fyear) {

                flag++;
                updateStatus(id, "Missed");

            }

               else

            if(cday==fday && cmonth==fmonth && cyear>fyear) {

                    flag++;
                    updateStatus(id, "Missed");

            }

               else

            if(cmonth>fmonth && cyear>fyear) {

                    flag++;
                    updateStatus(id, "Missed");

            }

               else

            if(cmonth>fmonth && cyear==fyear) {

                    flag++;
                    updateStatus(id, "Missed");

            }

            result = flag;


        }


        return result;
    }
```

As you can see, I have to compare every possible case for the date being ahead. And I personally think it's not the most efficient method. 
Any advice?

Comment: Coming up with the worst possible way to compare two Java dates would be an *accomplishment.*

Comment: It feels to me like the first problem is your storage. If you could pick a saner storage format, it would make your life a *lot* simpler. Work on that first, and then consider the comparison part. (Hint: just construct two `Calendar` objects and you can easily compare those...)

Comment: agree with Jon - save this as one date in the database - then everything is pretty simple.

Comment: Unrelated tip: You can just do while(c.moveToNext()) instead of your for loop. Also, don't forget to close your cursor when you're done..

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you! I'll do that.
 My earlier plans were to just display the date. Hance, this absurd storage type.

Comment: @K_K: Why does "I want to display the date" suggest that you should store it in a strange way? There are plenty of tools to display dates when stored sensibly...

Comment: @JonSkeet I used the date picker fragment to enable the user to pick the date. As it returns three separate values, I just stringed it together under one column, like, `day + "\" + month + "\" + year`.

Comment: If you store as a Date object (or as a Long if you are so inclined), you can then format your date for display using a class like SimpleDateFormat.  Generally mixing data storage and data display format is a bad idea.

Comment: @K_K: It would be better to convert it to a more sensible representation as soon as possible, and work with that for as much of the time as possible. (If you can, use Joda Time... that may be overkill on Android though.)

Comment: The problem with Calendar compare is that they wont indicate if it is the same day, because it is based in milliseconds.

Comment: One question so much to learn! Thank you so much, people.

Comment: @Pyrodante so the better option will be?

Comment: I would concur with Raghav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never really worked with dates, but I'll outline an algorithm that at least reduces the number of comparisons you need to make.

```
if(currentYear > dataYear) {
    //We're obviously past that date. Move on
} else if(currentYear == dataYear) {
    //We're in the same year. Let's check for months
    if(currentMonth > dataMonth) {
        //Missed the date again, move on
    } else if(currentMonth == dataMonth) {
        //We're in the same year and the same month! Let's check days
        if(currentDay > dataDay) {
            //Date is still in the past. Keep moving on
        } else if(currentDay == dataDay) {
            //Date is today
        } else {
            //Date is in the future
        }
    }
} else {
    //Date is in the past
}
```

This isn't going to be terrible efficient either, and you could probably cut down on the number of if statements by using `&&` strategically (though compiler optimization might do it for you anyways).

A better approach would be to save the date in UNIX time, and get the current UNIX time and just compare the two longs. Can't get much simpler than that.

You could also construct another Calendar object from your stored date and use [before()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29). However, a primitive long vs long comparison will be more efficient than comparing two Calendars.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking to reduce my algo in a similar manner but I think I'm just going to change the storage type in my database.

Comment: @K_K Definitely. Comparing two longs is infinitely easier than nested if statements and what not. You can always convert it to days/months/years when you need to display it.

Answer (score 2):

suggest using the joda datetime library for date comparison, has some useful features like isBefore and isAfter

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for the comparison

```
Date now = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(now); // make sure the time part is the same
for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
    String id = c.getString(iRow);

    int fday = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iDay));
    int fmonth = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMonth));
    int fyear = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iYear));

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, fyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, fmonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, fday);
    Date d = cal.getTime();
    if (now.after(d)) {
        flag++;
        updateStatus(id, "Missed");
    }

    result = flag;
}
```